# Detect web service accessibility using JScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, jscript

Is there a common way to detect whether a web service is accessible, through javascript?
For example, if the web server is down or IIS on it is stopped, I can stop the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to send a request to the server, and listen for errors (i.e.: timeout)

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://somewebsite.com",
  type: "POST"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html("Website is up.");
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
  $("#log").html("Website is down.");
});
```